# How to insert multiple values with MySQL

Tags: mysql

There probably isn't a way to do this but I thought I would ask and put it to rest.

I'm using a stored procedure to insert data into a table. I then need to insert multiple values into a second associated table using a second procedure. The second table can have zero or many values and will use the last_insert_id from the first insert. I want to call procedure two from procedure one which isn't an issue, however, how do I insert my values into the second table when I don't know how many values there will be?

I can easily do this with application code but the requirement is to use procedures. Is there a way to pass an array of values (so to speak) into procedure one for use in the second procedure insert?

The array returned from my application code would look like this (or may even be empty):

```
Array(
  [0] => 4
  [1] => 10
  [2] => 3
)
```

If I knew that there would **always** be exactly x number of values, I could simply do this:

```
INSERT INTO table2(col1,col2)
VALUES(v1,v2), (v3,v4), (v5,v6)
```

If I'm using a procedure and don't know how many values are to be inserted, how do I *package* those values to be inserted into table2? They'd have to go through procedure 1 and passed to procedure 2. I'm just not sure how to do this or even if it can be done.

Comment: Can you just do something like "INSERT SELECT" eg INSERT INTO TABLE_A (col1, col2) SELECT val1, val2 FROM TABLE_B

Comment: Joe, I don't think that will work. What I wind up with is an array of INT values that needs to go into an association table. Table1 returns the id and then I take that id and *somehow* insert this array of values into table2. My main goal is to keep all of the inserts together and happening at the same time.

Comment: Can we see some code? Is the issue that you need a dynamic way to create a column list for `INSERT`?

Comment: @njk, I have no code yet as I'm still wondering if this can be done. I'm not sure what you mean by a column list. The issue is that I will have an unknown number of values to insert into table2, so how do I make the insert? I can't pass an actual array of values (at least to my knowledge). Each value passed into the procedure has to be listed as an IN parameter. If I don't know how many need to be passed in, then how would this work?

Comment: I would say it's possible. I have scripts that generate the column list for an `INSERT`.

Comment: @njk, OK, so is a 'column list' what I need to do this? Could you provide an example for me to look at please?

Comment: @user1709311 The example I have is [from my own website](http://www.jadito.us/2012/08/28/rows-to-column-header-using-dynamic-t-sql/) using T-SQL. You would have to search for questions on how to transpose rows to columns in MySQL and follow the basic idea of the post.

Comment: @njk, I'm sorry but I'm not following you on this. How would a list of rows help me here?

Comment: @user1709311 You could store the columns in a temporary table as rows, or fetch the table schema

Comment: You wrote: "The issue is that I will have an unknown number of values to insert into table2"   What is unclear is whether those "values" you refer to are rows or columns.  If rows, I believe my solution in comment 1 works.  If columns, njk can help.

Comment: You also wrote "Table1 returns the id and then I take that id and somehow insert this array of values into table2"  but what turns the single id into an array of values?  Are you saying all the ids will become key->value pairs?  To me, it really isn't clear what you're proposing.